# Netcore 2.0 publish is not copying SDK dlls

Tags: msbuild, publish, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to publish a Netcore 2.0 application with MSBUILD.

The published output is missing all the SDK dlls such as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll (there are a lot) so when I try to run the application from command line with dotnet appname.dll I get the error saying that it can't find the referenced dll...

I have published other applications before (not created by me) and the publish copies the dlls and also has a "refs" folder which mine does not have.
So I am pretty sure it's a project configuration issue but I have been searching for hours and there is no information on what I should change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a nuget reference on my project called Microsoft.AspNetCore.All...

For some reason uninstalling this reference solved the issue and now the publish output contains all the SDK dlls

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.All is actually the only reference you *should* have

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET Core dlls are part of the runtime store that is included in the runtime & hosting bundle installations so they don't need to be included in the publish output. (note that this is going to [change in the 2.1 timeframe](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/issues/248))

To disable the use of the ASP.NET Core runtime package store, you can set this in your project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```